# Redirect stdout/stderr to ncurses window

Tags: c, stdout, ncurses

I'm currently adapting an old C console program to a ncurses application.
Many prints are done with `printf()` or `fprintf(stdout,...)` calls.

I would like to redirect `stdout` (and `stderr`) stream(s) to a new stream, poll on it, read whatever is available and print it in a ncurses window. I tried several things but cannot make it work...

Do someone ever achieved this? Is there a way?

Many thanks in advance.

PS: I know I can simply replace all the calls to `printw()` but I would like to launch the program in both the "new" and "old" graphic modes, so redirecting `stdout` is -- IMO -- the most elegant way.

Comment: The old program, are you running it as a separate process, or are you actually refactoring its code to be ncurses based instead? If you're refactoring it, then why not bite the bullet and actually search for all output and replace it with corresponding ncurses print calls?

Comment: Ncurses writes to stdout, so no, you can't even do this by replacing the C std runtime code. You'll need to write wrapper functions around your I/O calls to satisfy your requirements.

Comment: Run the old program in a sub process and interact with it via `stdin` and `stdout`?

Comment: If you want curses output, you must use curses functions to produce it.  The standard I/O streams will write to standard output, which is where the output to `stdscr` will go, but the output will be positioned wherever the cursor happens to be when `stdout` is flushed — which is not the effect you want.  You will have to intercept the calls and make them go via the curses library.  If you want the old behaviour too, you need to abstract the I/O calls so that you either call those using the `curses` library or those using plain old Standard I/O — and choose which when the program runs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by reading the pipe (which comes in on *stdin*) and using [`newterm`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-newterm) to open the output onto *stderr*, leaving *stdout* available for pipe/output.  If you want to continue reading from the pipe, you can tell `newterm` to use another suitable terminal input (even *stderr*).

That's a standard feature of X/Open Curses.